# APK file size doubled after build with cordova-android 9.0.0

Tags: android, cordova

I am building an Android App in release mode and the `apk` file size is double the last time I built it. I have done some changes, I updated plugins but also I have updated the Cordova version. I am building currently with Cordova-android release 9.0.0 and before with the release 8.1.0. And I guess this has something to do with this issue.

I have updated the Cordova-android release because I want to update the app to the API-level 29.
When the app is built for API-level 28 (or Cordova-android 8.1.0) the size of the apk is 60MB. But the app is built with Cordova-android 9.0.0, then the file size is 140MB.

If I extract both apks the size of the extracted files is pretty similar.

The commands I am using are:

`Cordova platform add android`

`Cordova build android --release`

Maybe anyone knows anything about this issue?

Comment: When you extract the apk the size is pretty similar? That doesn't make much sense to me. An APK is just a ZIP. If you extract it you should be able to see which part takes more space.

Comment: There are many different files (two folders are new in the apk built with 9.0.0) in both apks but the size of them is the same: 173MB in the apk built with cordova-android 9.0.0 and 177MB in the apk built with 8.1.0

Answer (score 0):

When you upgrade cordova-android to 9.0.0, and then build, is there any error occured, when I upgrade, this error happened, Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.version-check']

> Cannot parse project property android.injected.testOnly='fasle' of type 'class java.lang.String' as boolean. Expected 'true' or 'false'.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).